# compiler adding random characters to my char array

Tags: c++, char

I have a function called SearchArray() which calls another function called SearchRecords(char StudentNo[]) to check the database array of gRecs for a match in student numbers.

When i run the debugger the value of StudentNo is being shown as `StudentNo = 0x22fde0 "12345678"` if `StudentNum = "12345678"`. 
What are these additional characters?

SearchArray() function

```
  void SearchArray(){
    char studentNum[8];
    cout << "Enter student number: ";
    cin >> studentNum;

    char i =  SearchRecords(studentNum); 
    if (gRecs[i].studentNumber != studentNum){
        cout << "Record not found" << endl;
    }
    else {
        PrintRecord(i);
    }
}
```

SearchRecords() function

```
int SearchRecords(char StudentNo[])
{

for (int i = 0; i < gNumRecs; i++){
    if(gRecs[i].studentNumber == StudentNo)
    {
        return i;
    }
}
return -1; //not found
}
```

Comment: Where do you see additional characters ?

Comment: when I use the debugger to test the code.. as when I run it, even if there is a match, its not recognised due to these additional characters...

Comment: These additional characters: 0x22fde0? That's the address of `StudentNo`.

Comment: When you input `12345678`, each digit fills an element in `studentNum`, there should not be any additional characters.

Comment: `gRecs[i].studentNumber == StudentNo` is comparing the **addresses** of two character strings, not the  characters in the strings. You want `strcmp(gRecs[i].studentNumber, StudentNo) == 0` or something like  `std::string((gRecs[i].studentNumber) == std::string(StudentNo)`

Comment: cin >> studentNum;
Think you should read http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt

Comment: ohh i gotcha, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the "0x22fde0"? Those aren't in your character array, your character array only contains the part in quotes ("12345678"). The hexadecimal number 0x22fde0 is the address of the first character. In C/C++, any array is really just a pointer to the first element: the value of the variable is the address of the first element. So the debugger is showing you that address value. But it also knows that character arrays usually store strings, so it is also helpfully showing you the contents of that array as a string.

Comment: ...with the usual caveat about an array in C and C++ being, in most contexts, _converted_ to a pointer to its first element. The array itself is an array.

Answer (score 1):

As this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42870441/compiler-adding-random-characters-to-my-char-array#comment72846685_42870441) notes, you're comparing pointers not strings. You'll save yourself many headaches by changing your studentNumber type to std::string. This will allow you to use comparison operators(==,!=,<,<=,>,>=) with either a std::string or a raw string(char*) on the right side. I highly recommend reading up on strings at [tutorialspoint.com](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_strings.htm) and [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/).

When posting in the future, please post any relevant custom data structures(such as the layout of your gRecs element type), it helps us solve the problem faster.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, will do.